# Why browsers reveal fingerprinting information?

Tags: browser, default, privacy, fingerprinting

According to https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/ my Chrome and Firefox browsers disclose seemingly unnecessary information. Why those (and possibly other) browsers readily reveal any of that information?

Fingerprinting information that has nothing to do with serving:

1. Hardware concurrency
2. Device memory
3. Platform

Fingerprinting information that is needed only rarely (if at all) for serving:

1. User agent: browser and version
2. HTTP_ACCEPT headers: system language
3. List of browsers plugins
4. Timezone
5. Screen size and color depth; canvas hash
6. Audiocontext
7. WebGL vendor and renderer; WebGL hash

Answer (score 1):

I think your'e mischaracterising this. Browsers don't deliberately reveal fingerprintable information; they provide information that is useful in lots of different contexts that also happens to contribute to fingerprinting.

Whether these are relevant for serving can't be determined from the client end. Historically, user agent and screen size/depth were critical in the days before the heavy dependence we now see on Javascript to achieve similar things, when differences between browsers and client platforms was much greater, and many sites are still built that way. For example my bank's web site still has obvious, visible workarounds for IE6. Prior to CSS media queries (around 2009), many things could only be achieved by telling the server about these things, and many of those browsers are still with us.

Knowing whether a browser supports a particular plug-in can also be critical - for example if I want to render a PDF in an iframe, your browser had better be able to render it, and it's useful for a server to know if it can *before* trying to use it.

You missed off fonts and battery level from your list. These are also very often part of a fingerprint, but at the same time useful for sites to know what to serve to a client.

Some clients deliberately add noise to these values. For example whether a battery is at 10.4% or 12.6% doesn't really make much difference – it's quite low, so adding 5% noise to this information retains its utility while reducing identifiability.

Precisely how much noise you need to add to preserve anonymity, or at least provide reasonable (and measurable) ambiguity of identity, is covered by the concept of *differential privacy*, which I'll leave you to read up on.